# не простой поиск строки в gdb

Tags: отладка, gdb, reverse-engineering

Подскажите пожалуйста как в бинарном файле пользуясь отладчиком `gdb` найти строку или референс на нее? Пользоваться `find` вариантов нет так как файл обрезан и исходников нет. И есть ли в данном отладчике такая возможность?

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял gdb такое не умеет. Единственное что можно сделать, это в ручную шерстить секции с данными используя команду `x/Ns <address>` где `N` - количество выводимых блоков, а `<adress>` это стартовый адрес от которого отсчитывается `N` блоков.  Например `x/10s 0x00415fc8`.

Самый легкий и быстрый способ что я нашел, это воспользоватся утилитой `readelf` с флагом `-x`, значением необходимой к прочтению секции (в моем случае это было `.rodata`) и непосредственно название самой программы.
Выглядит так:
`readelf -x .rodata sell`
Оттуда достаем адрес необходимой строки и уже в отладчике ставим на данный адрес (при необходимости) точку останова.